# Something about setInterval() and an animation

Tags: javascript

I met a problem when I use the `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` to finish a animation that when click the button,the opacity of the backgroundcolor can be show or fade in the process of time, not at once; The fade function is good, but the show is not

I have found the problem by using `console.log()`.

```js
var divNode = document.getElementById("fade-obj");
var btnNode = document.getElementById("fade-btn")
divNode.style.opacity = 1;

function fade() {
  divNode.style.opacity = divNode.style.opacity - 0.1;
  console.log(divNode.style.opacity)
}

function show() {
  divNode.style.opacity = divNode.style.opacity + 0.1;
  console.log(divNode.style.opacity)
}

function startFade() {
  if (btnNode.innerHTML == "fade") {
    ii = setInterval(fade, 100);
    btnNode.disabled = true;
    var setTime = setTimeout(function() {
      btnNode.innerHTML = "show";
      clearInterval(ii);
      divNode.style.opacity = 0;
      btnNode.disabled = false;
    }, 1000)
  } else if (btnNode.innerHTML == "fade") {
    ij = setInterval(show, 100);
    btnNode.disabled = true;
    var setTime1 = setTimeout(function() {
      btnNode.innerHTML = "show";
      clearInterval(ij);
      divNode.style.opacity = 1;
      btnNode.disabled = false;
    }, 1000)
  }
}

btnNode.addEventListener("click", startFade)
```

```html
<div id="fade-obj" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:#000"></div>
<button id="fade-btn">fade</button>
```

The opacity will stop increasing when the `opacity == 0.1`. I want to know why and how to deal with the problem.Here is the code.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Your initial opacity is `''`. You need to add a check for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am the one asked the question
This is the correct code.
There is a mistake in the code on the question.
So sorry.

```
<script>
    var divNode=document.getElementById("fade-obj");
    var btnNode=document.getElementById("fade-btn")
    divNode.style.opacity=1;
    function fade(){                        
            divNode.style.opacity=divNode.style.opacity-0.1;
                                            console.log(divNode.style.opacity)
    }
    function show(){
            divNode.style.opacity=divNode.style.opacity+0.1;
            console.log(divNode.style.opacity)
    }

    function startFade(){
        if(btnNode.innerHTML=="fade"){
            ii=setInterval(fade,100);
            btnNode.disabled=true;
             var setTime = setTimeout(function(){
                btnNode.innerHTML="show";
                clearInterval(ii);
                divNode.style.opacity=0;
                btnNode.disabled=false;
               },1000)
        }
        else if(btnNode.innerHTML=="show"){
            ij=setInterval(show,100);
            btnNode.disabled=true;
            var setTime1 = setTimeout(function(){
                btnNode.innerHTML="fade";
                clearInterval(ij);
                divNode.style.opacity=1;
                btnNode.disabled=false;
               },1000)      
        }


    }   

    btnNode.addEventListener("click",startFade)
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting your opacity initially - the initial value is an empty string `''`.

I would add a check for this and default it to 1 in this case. You can do this by adding to your `show` and `fade` functions:

```js
const oldOpacity = parseFloat(
  divNode.style.opacity === '' ? 1 : divNode.style.opacity
)
```

Here is the updated version implementing this:

```js
var divNode = document.getElementById('fade-obj')
var btnNode = document.getElementById('fade-btn')

function fade() {
  const oldOpacity = parseFloat(
    divNode.style.opacity === '' ? 1 : divNode.style.opacity
  )
  divNode.style.opacity = oldOpacity - 0.1
  console.log(divNode.style.opacity)
}

function show() {
  const oldOpacity = parseFloat(
    divNode.style.opacity === '' ? 1 : divNode.style.opacity
  )
  divNode.style.opacity = oldOpacity + 0.1
  console.log(divNode.style.opacity)
}

function startFade() {
  if (btnNode.innerHTML === 'fade') {
    const ii = setInterval(fade, 100)
    btnNode.disabled = true
    var setTime = setTimeout(function() {
      btnNode.innerHTML = 'show'
      clearInterval(ii)
      divNode.style.opacity = 0
      btnNode.disabled = false
    }, 1000)
  } else if (btnNode.innerHTML === 'show') {
    const ij = setInterval(show, 100)
    btnNode.disabled = true
    var setTime1 = setTimeout(function() {
      btnNode.innerHTML = 'show'
      clearInterval(ij)
      divNode.style.opacity = 1
      btnNode.disabled = false
    }, 1000)
  }
}

btnNode.addEventListener('click', startFade)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to convert opacity into a number using [unary operator(+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus):

```js
var divNode = document.getElementById("fade-obj");
var btnNode = document.getElementById("fade-btn")
divNode.style.opacity = 1;

function fade() {
  divNode.style.opacity = +divNode.style.opacity - 0.1;
  console.log(divNode.style.opacity)
}

function show() {
  divNode.style.opacity = +divNode.style.opacity + 0.1;
  console.log(divNode.style.opacity)
}

function startFade() {
  if (btnNode.innerHTML == "fade") {
    ii = setInterval(fade, 100);
    btnNode.disabled = true;
    var setTime = setTimeout(function() {
      btnNode.innerHTML = "show";
      clearInterval(ii);
      divNode.style.opacity = 0;
      btnNode.disabled = false;
    }, 1000)
  } else if (btnNode.innerHTML == "show") {
    ij = setInterval(show, 100);
    btnNode.disabled = true;
    var setTime1 = setTimeout(function() {
      btnNode.innerHTML = "fade";
      clearInterval(ij);
      divNode.style.opacity = 1;
      btnNode.disabled = false;
    }, 1000)
  }
}

btnNode.addEventListener("click", startFade)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="fade-obj" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:#000"></div>
<button id="fade-btn">fade</button>
```